# PyPlot move alternative y axis to background

Tags: python, matplotlib

In pyplot, you can change the order of different graphs using the `zorder` option or by changing the order of the `plot()` commands. However, when you add an alternative axis via `ax2 = twinx()`, the new axis will always overlay the old axis (as described in the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.twinx)).

Is it possible to change the order of the axis to move the alternative (twinned) y-axis to background?

In the example below, I would like to display the blue line on top of the histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

# Data
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, 0.1)
y = np.power(x,2)

y2 = 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi) * np.exp(-y/2)
data = [random.gauss(0.0, 1.0) for i in range(1000)]

# Plot figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.hist(data, bins=40, normed=True, color='g',zorder=0)
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='r', linewidth=2, zorder=2)
ax1.plot(x, y, color='b', linewidth=2, zorder=5)

ax1.set_ylabel("Parabola")
ax2.set_ylabel("Normal distribution")

ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('b')
ax2.yaxis.label.set_color('r')

plt.show()
```

Edit: For some reason, I am unable to upload the image generated by this code. I will try again later.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can set the `zorder` of an axes, `ax.set_zorder()`. One would then need to remove the background of that axes, such that the axes below is still visible.

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_zorder(10)
ax1.patch.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: I like to follow this guidance http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Control-twinx-series-zorder-ax2-series-behind-ax1-series-or-place-ax2-on-left-ax1-on-right-td12994.html and use `ax1.set_zorder(ax2.get_zorder()+1)`

Comment: For a question on how to plot different artists from different axes on top of each other, see [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619933/interchanging-the-zorders-on-individual-artists-from-two-axes)

Comment: FYI it's very important to remove the background of that axes, such that the axes below and their graphs are visible.