# Interchanging the zorders on individual artists from two axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure on which I plot two axes-objects, `ax1` and `ax2`, where `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`.

How can I interchange the zorders on *individual* artists from each of the axes? E.g., I would like one artist from `ax1` to be in the very background, then have all artists from `ax2` on top of that, and then plot the rest of the artists from `ax1`. As an example, I would like to plot the following in the order in which it is written (i.e., `(x3, y3)` on top of `(x2, y2)` on top of `(x1, y1)`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax2.plot(x2, y2)
ax1.plot(x3, y3)
```

How can this be done?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646756/5748367) shows how to reverse the zorders of the axes, but not on individual items.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: @DizietAsahi Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot simply adjust the z-order of artists across axes. The z-order of the Artists belonging to one `Axes` are relative to that axes only.

You can, however, obtain the desired effect, but no easily. Here are two options:

## Using 3 axes

The simplest way in my opinion is to use 3 axes, with the 3rd axis being a complete "clone" of the first one, but with a z-order above `ax2`.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax3 = fig.add_axes(ax1.get_position(), sharex=ax1, sharey=ax1)
ax3.set_facecolor('none') #prevents axes background from hiding artists below
ax3.set_axis_off() # pervents superimposed ticks from being drawn

l_bottom, = ax1.plot([1,2,3], [4,6,6], lw=10, c='C1')
l2, = ax2.plot([1,2,3], [60,30,40], lw=10, c='C2')
l_top, = ax3.plot([1,2,3],[5,10,3], lw=10, c='C3')
ax3.legend([l_bottom, l2, l_top],['left','right','left'])
ax3.set_title('using a 3rd axe')
```

[image]

## Using transforms

This methods only uses 2 axes, but plots the green line on `ax2` using the data-coordinates from `ax1`. The problem with that method is that ax1 will not autoscale automatically, hence the need to call `set_ylim()`. Plus it could get quite confusing in a larger code to keep track of which transform is used by which artist.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

l_bottom, = ax1.plot([1,2,3], [4,6,6], lw=10, c='C1')
l2, = ax2.plot([1,2,3], [60,30,40], lw=10, c='C2')
l_top, = ax2.plot([1,2,3],[5,10,3], lw=10, c='C3',transform=ax1.transData)
ax1.set_ylim(2.65,10.35)  # matches the limits on the previous graph
ax2.set_ylim(28.5,61.5)
ax2.legend([l_bottom, l2, l_top],['left','right','left'])
ax2.set_title('using transforms')
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. This would benefit from using the same axis limits in both cases, since currently it looks like there is a difference between the two cases, which is not the case at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tweaked the code a bit and updated the resulting image in case this could be useful for somebody else