# Pandas: How can I plot with separate y-axis, but still control the order?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series, axis

I am trying to plot multiple time series in one plot. The scales are different, so they need separate y-axis, and I want a specific time series to have its y-axis on the right. I also want that time series to be behind the others. But I find that when I use `secondary_y=True`, this time series is always brought to the front, even if the code to plot it comes before the others. How can I control the order of the plots when using `secondary_y=True` (or is there an alternative)?

Furthermore, when I use `secondary_y=True` the y-axis on the left no longer adapts to appropriate values. Is there a fixed for this?

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dummy data 
lenx = 1000
x = range(lenx)
np.random.seed(4)
y1 = np.random.randn(lenx)
y1 = pd.Series(y1, index=x)
y2 = 50.0 + y1.cumsum()

# plot time series.
# use ax to make Pandas plot them in the same plot.
ax = y2.plot.area(secondary_y=True)
y1.plot(ax=ax)
```

So what I would like is to have the blue area plot behind the green time series, and to have the left y-axis take appropriate values for the green time series:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QzPV.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following using [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) instead of using `secondary_y`, and then following the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645280/pyplot-move-alternative-y-axis-to-background) to move the twinned axis to the background:

```
# plot time series.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y1.plot(ax=ax, color='green')
ax.set_zorder(10)
ax.patch.set_visible(False)

ax1 = ax.twinx()
y2.plot.area(ax=ax1, color='blue')
```

[image]