# How to change the order of these plots using zorder?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, z-order

I'm trying to get a line plot to be over the bar plot. But no matter what I do to change the zorder, it seems like it keeps the bar on top of the line. Nothing I do to try to change zorder seems to work. Sometimes the bar plot just doesn't show up if zorder is <= 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def tail_plot(tail):

    plt.figure()

    #line plot
    ax1 = incidence[incidence['actual_inc'] != 0].tail(tail).plot(x='date', y=['R_t', 'upper 95% CI', 'lower 95% CI'], color = ['b', '#808080', '#808080'])
    ax1.set_zorder(2)

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    inc = incidence[incidence['actual_inc'] != 0]['actual_inc'].tail(tail).values

    dates = incidence[incidence['actual_inc'] != 0]['date'].tail(tail).values

    #bar plot
    ax2.bar(dates, inc, color ='red', zorder=1)  
    ax2.set_zorder(1)
```

Keeps giving me this:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyPlot move alternative y axis to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645280/pyplot-move-alternative-y-axis-to-background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the approach in the post is that `ax1` has a white background which totally occludes the plot of `ax2`. To solve this, the background color can be set to 'none'.

Note that the `plt.figure()` in the example code of the post creates an empty plot because the pandas plot creates its own new figure (as no `ax` is given explicitly).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({f'curve {i}': 20 + np.random.normal(.1, .5, 30).cumsum() for i in range(1, 6)})

# line plot
ax1 = df.plot()
ax1.set_zorder(2)
ax1.set_facecolor('none')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# bar plot
x = np.arange(30)
ax2.bar(x, np.random.randint(7 + x, 2 * x + 10), color='red', zorder=1)
ax2.set_zorder(1)
plt.show()
```

[image: demo plot]

Comment: That did it! Thanks!