# Pandas Stacked Bar and Plot Issues

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to overlay a stacked bar with a line plot. Running off pandas 0.25.3 working in vscode jupyter notebook. I have plotted this numerous times with different data sets using the relatively standard way below - but in this case I only get the latter matplot object plotted

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2=ax.twinx()
df1.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, ax=ax)
df2.plot(ax=ax2,linestyle='-', marker='o')
```

df1 and df2 by design have the same index. I have also tried merging these in case that was the driving issue as well as combinations using secondary_y, setting ax2 object to the matplot object. I tried the below work around too and tried simplifying to a bar chart on the primary axis. Secondary and primary line graphs plot fine too, so no issue with the underlying data (nan free etc)

[pandas DataFrame how to mix bar and line plots with different scales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457861/pandas-dataframe-how-to-mix-bar-and-line-plots-with-different-scales)

Data is the form as below (when joined) - where col3 is the line plot, col1 and col2 are the stacked bars

```
idx   col1    col2    col3
1.0    0.2    0.8    0.6
2.0    0.1    0.9    0.52
3.0    0.1    0.9    0.5
4.0    0.05    0.95    0.43
```

There are numerous questions asking similar on this site, but they tend to be more for beginners. Am I missing a version compatibility issue? I've written this plot before in 30secs but have spent too much time trying to figure out the issue here. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Is this a case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645280/pyplot-move-alternative-y-axis-to-background

Comment: I did see that too and doesn't seem to be the solution. Slightly pulling my hair out here.

Comment: Does the sample data represent your actual data? Specifically, is your data time-indexed? If not, how many rows are there in your data?

Comment: The data is representative - 8 rows, 13 columns. Index is float. First 12 columns sum to 1 (100%), with the final column a decaying function  <1, > 0.

Comment: Update here - I ended up getting this to plot by setting the index to type str!

Comment: Is this intentional design when index is of type float?

Comment: @QuangHoang - I appreciate the questioning above - it got me thinking about the datatype of the index....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple resetting of the datatype of the index did the trick for me here:

```
df1.index = df1.index.astype(str)
df2.index = df2.index.astype(str)
```

There is some loss of functionality as I had been plotting a vline between ticks, but this appears to be the best solution I could find.