# How to draw a bar graph behind a line graph in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a plot with a bar graph and a line graph on two separate axes. I want the bar graph to appear behind the line graph.

```
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() # ax1 is line graph, ylabel on the left
    ax2 = ax1.twinx() # ax2 is bar graph, ylabel on the right
```

If I set the axes in this order, the bar graph appears on top. However if I swap them, then the y label positions swap as well. How can I make the bar graph appear behind the line graph, while keeping the positions of the y labels in place?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [PyPlot move alternative y axis to background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645280/pyplot-move-alternative-y-axis-to-background)

The solution is to set the ax1 zorder higher than ax2 and disable the ax1 background.